# SQLite prepared vs non-prepared query - Different results (PySide, python)

Tags: python, sqlite, pyside

Python, PySide, SQLite:

Im probably missing something obvious, but im getting different results with the same (or so i thought) query. I Should be seeing the results of the non-prepared query (afaik).

Thank you for any and all help!

prepared:

```
    filteringCategory = "store"
    from_date = '2014-03-01'
    to_date = '2014-03-29'
    query.prepare("SELECT s.name AS store, SUM(price) AS total_price FROM expenses AS e JOIN expenses_to_store AS ets ON e.expenses_id = ets.expenses_id JOIN store AS s ON ets.store_id = s.store_id WHERE date BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date GROUP BY :group")
    query.bindValue(":from_date", from_date)
    query.bindValue(":to_date", to_date)
    query.bindValue(":group", filteringCategory)
    query.exec_()
```

non-prepared:

```
query.exec_("SELECT price, s.name AS store, SUM(price) AS total_price FROM expenses AS e JOIN expenses_to_store AS ets ON e.expenses_id = ets.expenses_id JOIN store AS s ON ets.store_id = s.store_id WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-29' GROUP BY store")
```

[image: query result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem could be the line:

```
    query.bindValue(":group", filteringCategory)
```

which is attempting to bind a parameter which is not a *value*. I don't think binding column or table names is allowed, because that would change the actual structure of the SQL statement.

Instead, you would need to do something like:

```
    "SELECT ... :from_date AND :to_date GROUP BY %s" % filteringCategory
```

Comment: Bound parameters indeed have to correspond to something value-like, because of how they're used by the internal VM code, whereas column names and so on change what the VM code _is in the first place_.

Comment: Ah, i was actually aware of that already. Sometimes i just forget the fundamentals. Thanks a lot!